# How to load images and insert images after publishing winforms c# project

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I have putted image folder to  \bin\Debug.It was fine when i debug and run code without installing to it machine.After publishing the project i am not able to see images .

Any one there who can give me some idea and reason behind that?

Comment: Yes because after Publishing Bin/Debug folder is not shipped with your .exe File.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the property "Copy to Output Directory" of the report file to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer". This will copy the Images below the actual output directory during a build and you can access it with

`Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images", "img.jpg").`

or

Try this by creating a folder in your appliation folder:

```
static string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        static string debug = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        static string bin = Path.GetDirectoryName(debug);
        static string DefaultLayoutFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(bin);
public string cImage = DefaultLayoutFilePath + "\\Images\\img.png";
```

Comment: Its working fine for stored image in image folder and what to do when i have to add new image to a image folder problematically.Do new image will be seen after publishing

Comment: yes if you add images in this folder they will be shown, just set the path when you are trying to save an image programmatically.

Comment: I am seeing images only during programming running and when i clean the visual studio program i am not seeing images

Comment: Ok try this, add a folder Name="Images" inside it put all your images. Now use the second method I have given you, it will surely work.

Comment: How to publish many folder of images under project dir in visual studio i.e i have two image folder image1 and image two.Image 1 and image 2 folder are dynamically populated with images .I have tried and its ok for Image 1 folder and its not working for image 2 folder after publishing .without publishing its working fine

Comment: as far as I can get you Ganesh, you are giving path for Image1 as above but not for Image2, as for me it worked with5 folders as I had Default, Custom, Image etc. folders that are to be populated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder for your data files somewhere, ideally not down the bin folder path.  I usually create mine in the same folder as the solution file.

Next, you need to right click on the project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer (the "StartUp" project if you have more than one).  Select the Debug tab and point the "Working directory" to your data folder.  This needs to be done for each Build Configuration you use.  You can change the build configuration that you are configuring at the top of the Properties window you just opened.

Now when you run the code from Visual Studio, it will run as if your executable is in the data folder rather than down the bin folder path.

If you want to "ship" your application, you can copy the data folder somewhere else on your computer, rename it to something more sensible, copy in your exe and it *should* run just fine.  I say should because there may be more files your exe needs other than the data such as dlls, but if your project is fairly simple this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all of your images inside your application. Right-click on your solution and pick *Properties -> Resources*

Place your pictures there and save it by pressing *Ctrl + S*. Now you're ready to publish it.

P.S.
To embed resources in a .resx file you can right click on each (or all) of your pictures in Resources and in Properties select *Persistence -> Embedded in .resx*

Comment: How to publish many folder of images under project dir in visual studio i.e i have two image folder image1 and image two.Image 1 and image 2 folder are dynamically populated with images .I have tried and its ok for Image 1 folder and its not working for image 2 folder after publishing .without publishing its working fine